# Why is the local variable getting modified in another instance of another function in call by value?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        backtrack(list, "", 0, 0, n);
        return list;
    }
    
    public void backtrack(List<String> list, String str, int open, int close, int max){
        
        if(str.length() == max*2){
            list.add(str);
            return;
        }
        
        if(open < max)
            backtrack(list, str+"(", open+1, close, max);
        if(close < open)
            backtrack(list, str+")", open, close+1, max);
    }
```

In the above code 'list' is a List of strings defined in `generateParenthesis()`. In  `backtrack(list, "", 0, 0, n);` they don't store the value of list returned by `backtrack()` but when the final list is returned in `return list;` the value of list is as returned by `backtrack()`

My question is: why is the instance of 'list' variable created in `generateParenthesis()` getting modified even though it is not a static variable and neither is the value returned by `backtrack()` function is being stored in 'list' by using an assignment operation like `list=backtrack(list, "", 0, 0, n);` ?

Comment: IMHO the confusion already starts when you talk about `list` being a List of strings. It is **not** a List of strings - it is **a reference** to a List of strings. And anyone having a copy of that reference (to a List of strings) can manipulate that referenced List of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses, as you said, pass by value when talking about function calls.

If you had something like that:

```
static void process(int a) {
    a = a + 3;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    process(a);
    System.out.println(a); // still 5
}
```

`a = 5` would be your final value.

Now, in the case of objects (also the `Lists`, which are still objects), you are still passing by value, but the value stored in the `List` object sent as a parameter is a reference to the instance of the object in memory.

On the heap, you have a `List` instance, and on the stack, you have a `List` object. Whenever you call a method on a `List` object, it is called on the single instance from the heap. So `List` will get modified.

A good example which shows that a pass by value happens in your case is trying to modify the instance your object refers to:

```
public void backtrack(List<String> list, String str, int open, int close, int max){
    list = new ArrayList<String>(); // this should reset the list, but only resets it within the function. It won't get modified outside the function
```